# Laravel get all data through pivot Table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, relationship

Hello I've got problem with getting the name of Group which Recipent is member.

I use 3 tables for that subject : recipent, group and group_recipent.

In group_recipent table I've got only columns like recipent_id and group_id. All is correct to Laravel naming convention.

It's my Recipent model:

```
 public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class)->withPivot('group_recipent', 'recipent_id', 'group_id');
}
```

And my Group model:

```
public function recipents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Recipent::class)->withPivot('group_recipent', 'recipent_id', 'group_id');
}
```

Accessing data:

```
$user = Recipent::find(4);
    
    $data="";

    foreach ($user->groups as $group)
    {
        $data .= $group->name ." ";
    }
    dd($data);
```

After trying to access the name of a group through pivot table I get an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'group_recipent.group_recipent' in 'field list' (SQL: select `groups`.*, `group_recipent`.`recipent_id` as `pivot_recipent_id`, `group_recipent`.`group_id` as `pivot_group_id`, `group_recipent`.`group_recipent` as `pivot_group_recipent` from `groups` inner join `group_recipent` on `groups`.`id` = `group_recipent`.`group_id` where `group_recipent`.`recipent_id` = 4)

I wanted to acces the name all names of group which recipent is member of but I get error like above. Have you any idea how to solve that? :/

Comment: can you dd group inside the foreach ?

Comment: No i Can't i dont know why

Comment: Okay so, do you have any record in the pivot table associated with recipent_id 4 ? If not add it. 
After that: $user = Recipent::find(4);
    
    $data="";

    foreach ($user->groups as $group)
    {
       dd($group);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete from your models 'group_recipent'. I assume you're wonder that the 1st field is pivot table name. It should look like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Recipent::class)->withPivot('recipent_id', 'group_id');
```

If someone got other idea, just add comment below.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't catch this. Why people dislike this answer? :/